# GXT, how to display the widgets labels with a VBOXLayout

Tags: gxt, label

I have been trying to resolve this by myself but I can't find any answers. I need the text fields the combo box, etc., to display its own label, but I can't put it to work on a panel different from the `FormPanel` (in which all works great). I'm trying to display the labels for a text field on a `VBoxLayout` but I don't find the way to do it.

I need to work with a `VBoxLayout` because I need the widgets to position in the middle of the form after the window is maximized or minimized and this layout is the only one that proves to work. Is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Add another LayoutContainer and then set the panel to use FormLayout for example

```
LayoutContainer innerPanel = new LayoutContainer();
innerPanel.setLayout(new FormLayout());
```

Now it will work just like a form panel.